# Module classpath in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, classpath, intellij-14

I have two projects, A project depend on B project, these two project was I checkout from svn,other people created them by eclipse.  But I use the intelliJ idea, in the web.xml:

```
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:config/spring-servlet.xml;classpath:config/spring-mybatis.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

The second `classpath:config/spring-mybatis.xml` was in project B, my idea can not find it. But if I open these two project in eclipse,eclipse can find it.
 How can I solve this problem？

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Is code showing up in red in IntelliJ, is the build failing, or both?

Comment: Both.When I run tomcat,console show me: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your `web.xml` file:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        config/spring-servlet.xml
        config/spring-mybatis.xml
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

You may need to change the above XML file paths so that Spring can find them.  It appears that Eclipse was somehow able to interpret `classpath` as an actual location to your XML files.  During a Maven build, the Spring config files get copied to the `WEB-INF/classes` directory.  It is likely that Eclipse was referring to these copied classpath XML files.

For more information and a good read, see [this Stack Exchange article](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145545/where-to-put-spring-configuration-file).

Comment: I did what you said,but the code is still showing up red,and console is still show me:Context [] startup failed due to previous errors.I think it's not the format's problem.I hope you could understand what I said...

Comment: Please post the stack trace from your Maven build.

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand what you said,you mean that you want look my pom.xml?

Comment: No, I want to see the errors which happen when you run your code.